# Matrix of Foreign Keys and free textfields in Django

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I try to create a model for a 24-well plate for sample storage. So this basically is a plate with 24 holes and the positions are organised by the Letters A-H and replicates 1-3.

I have already a model 'Sample', which saves all sample related informations and I want to have this Sample ForeignKey in my 24well plate position.

I am wondering now, if I have to create a Model with 24 model.ForeignKey fields, or is there a smarter way?

It would look like this in the end

```
position_A1 = model.ForeignKey('Sample')
position_A2 = model.ForeignKey('Sample')
position_A3 = model.ForeignKey('Sample')
position_B1 = model.ForeignKey('Sample')
position_B2 = model.ForeignKey('Sample')
...
position_H3 = model.ForeignKey('Sample')
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: oh, and I forgot the free textfield part...
Since Django nicely provides these drop down menus for the foreign keys, is there a way to have a alternative free text field? So in some cases, there is no sample, since the hole is dirty or other things... I would love to have a textfield instead.. or additionally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One model with 24 exact fields is not very good DB design. I don't know if this may be possible, but what happens if you start using 32-well plates? Instead, I would create a Hole/Well model with a foreign key to the Sample and any other data you might assign to it:

```
class Well(models.Model):
    sample = models.ForeignKey('Sample')
    letter = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    is_filled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...
```

With this approach you can get a Sample's wells, count them or annotate them. You can even leave out the "unfilled" ones if you want.

Comment: I had the same feeling, that my approach would be bad design, that's why I asked this question. I like the answer, Then I would just need a model Plate, where I can define how many wells are available. I will think about the right solution, thanks!